# How to copy the SOAP Response from soapui into a notepad

Tags: soapui, notepad

I have a webservice ,on running the webservice request my response gets me a Random 16 digit MemberNumber.I save this MemberNumber from response into a notepad using the following 
groovy code

```
----Xpath of the required tag in the soap response
def request = context.expand( '${CreateMember#Response# //ns2:CreateMemberResponse[1]/ns2:CreateMemberResult[1]/ns2:Epsilon[1]/ns2:Response[1]/ns2:GetMemberLookupReply[1]/ns2:Members[1]/ns2:Member[1]/ns2:MemberNumber[1]}')
--writing to a notepad
new File( "C:/Users/vikranth_sanka/Desktop/membernumber.txt" ).write(request, "UTF-8" )
```

1. on running this script membernumber is saved into this notepad(membernumber.txt)
2. When I run the same script again, this time new data overwrites the previously saved data in the notepad(i.e., membernumber.txt)
3. My Requirement is whenever I execute the Script the newly generated membernumber from my SOAP response should be appended to the data in the notepad(that means all the
   membernumbers generated from soap response should be stored in the same notepad seperated by a delimiter or space)

Comment: This one can be solved with a little bit of research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
new File( "C:/Users/vikranth_sanka/Desktop/membernumber.txt" ) << request
```

If all else fails, try the documentation: http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN2015-Files